# how to remove localstorage in javascript after some time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I have 5 stages on the signup page so I used the user id to check the user stage by storing his id in local storage. I want to remove the id from localstorage when users leave my website without filling the form. I want to remove local storage after some time.

Is it possible to remove items from local storage when the user is not on my website?

Comment: This is what session storage is for

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: you should use session for delete data after close browser && use cookie for managing storage by time (Ex: delete data after 30days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask) and [Samuel Liew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew) also suggested to use `sessionStorage` as per the requirement you have. But still if you want to use `localStorage` for any reasons. You can use :

```
localStorage.removeItem(<your item comes here>)
```

Called this inside `beforeDestroy()` hook as it called right before a vue instance destroy.

This will ensure that before the instance is removed from the DOM, we are removing an item from the `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session or cookie storage for that purpose, but if you want to use local storage then you can use onunload or onbeforeunload event listeners of JS and clear local storage on onunload. These listeners work perfectly on tab close or tab back button as well.